# Why is the class not found after PHP upgrade from 7.0 to 8.1?

Tags: php, class, php-8.1

I am migrating an older application from PHP 7.0 to 8.1 on an ubuntu system. The app is using a library called [MobileDetect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/). The readme of the latest verion of the library which I migrated to, states compatability only for PHP >=7.3,<8.0

As it is a lightweight library I was still hoping to be able to use it with php 8.1, however even the class call is failing:

Executing file:

```
require_once '../app_global/Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
```

File Mobile_Detect.php:

```
<?php
namespace Detection;
use BadMethodCallException;
class Mobile_Detect
{
...
```

PHP error log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Mobile_Detect" not found in 
/home/www/project/qry_index.inc:11\nStack trace...
```

The name space seems right, there is no capital letter misspelling, so why is the class not found?

Comment: First thing to do is to check whether the file is where you expect it to be.

Comment: Yes it is. If I change the name of the file, I do get the additional error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required ...

Comment: can you try changing the namespce to `Detection\MobileDetect` ?

Comment: or `$detect = new \Detection\MobileDetect;` ?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments under the Question, updating the namespace to:

```
namespace Detection\MobileDetect;
```

should work.

Another option (as mentioned in the README of the project) is to load the class as:

```
$detect = new \Detection\Mobile_Detect;
```

which should correctly load the class.